# Recommandations for small warehouse RFID management with detectors including batteries

Tags: bluetooth, rfid

As a computer technician, I have about 500 IT equipements to manage (hard drives, computers, displays, printers, a.s.o.).

I'm looking for a passive RFID equipment in order to know for each equipment in which location it is stored (office, whareouse, transit).

Please advise for beacons (detectors), RFID tags (stickers), and software.

**Technical constraints:**

The warehouse is underground and doesn't have any Internet connection.
The only electrical outlet is outside the deposit.

**Characteristics of the desired system:**

- **battery powered** RFID beacons that I can mount of the door posts (width 70 cm to 1 meter) and coming with a power button that I can toggle when coming at or leaving the warehouse.
- **capable to automatically update a portable device** in my pocket to tell if the object is in the warehouse, in transit, at the office, a.s.o.
  Multiple objects can pass through the door at the same time.
  Ideally the device would be a smarthone (Windows Phone or Android), so that I don't have to wear one more device. (If not possible, a Rapsberry PI running Linux or other device would be possible as well.)
- **standalone**, i.e. able to work totally offline (not requiring and Internet connection at any time)
- beacons preferably **not requiring WLAN** (WiFi) to communicate with the device, as I don't have Internet at the warehouse.
  (I'm aware about battery powered WLAN routers but would prefer the beacons communicating directly with the device through Bluetooth or else.)
- **connectable to at least one computer** about once a day to update an existing MySQL database.
- **using open standards for data storage** and not a proprietary "closed" system. Preferably using sqlite database format, or able to automatically generate SQL requests to update the database.
- **able to support stock growth** for future years (i.e. not limited to 500 items)
- if the software is able to support **further storage hierarchy**, so that I could mount RFID detectors on racks it would be nice, but this is not mandatory.
- if this is possible, able to reattribute used RFID sticker to a new object (once remaining quantity reached 0)

Hardware and softwares do not need to be bundled.
Free softwares and commercial ones are both welcome as long as they are good.

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: My solution so far has been improving what could be whilst staying low tech : better segregating what is stored where, improved storage, archive boxes, better labeling. Better organisation. Improvements are almost always possible on this side.